# How to bring WPF window to the front of TeamViewer dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, teamviewer

I need to bring my wpf window to the front of other windows.

I called this.Activate(), window shown, but when any teamviewer dialog opened, it can not be overlapped by other windows.

How can I hide it by my window?

[image: teamviewer dialog]

Comment: show your code please @asolovyov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to show your window over all the others is to use the Window property `TopMost = true`